# Blank page on register.php or login.php links when registering for a store

Tags: login

I am trying to register for a store to buy something and every time I try to register (or log in) I get a blank page. The site extension is always a `register.php` or a `login.php` and the URL will show the actual URL but the page is blank. Example screenshot below. I've tried with multiple stores and this is the case for every one of them. My security setting is set to standard and I'm not connected to any other VPN of any kind. Any ideas? FWIW I'm new to Tor and browsing onions in general. Here is the specific site I tried, but even more trusted services like TorShop are causing the same exact issue. Any ideas?

Onion Link: http://2ezyofc26j73hv3xxvsrnbc23dqxhgxqtk5ogcc7y6j5t6rlqquvhzid.onion/

[image: Tor Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For me, the website's login and registration pages show correctly (e.g. the registration page looks like this: [image]).

Perhaps a setting in the Tor browser was accidentally altered for you (maybe the browser was accidentally configured to block PHP, I don't know). Do you have an additional addons installed on the Tor Browser that weren't there by default?

I recommend uninstalling, then reinstalling the Tor browser and seeing if it works.
If that doesn't work, then it is likely that some other software application is interfering with the Tor Browser. You could try disabling software which you think might be an issue, but that might not solve the issue.

If none of these work, then report the issue to the Tor Project's Gitlab. They might be able to help. Here is the link: https://gitlab.torproject.org/.